# How can I add fields in the Sprout design your form?

Tags: plugin-sproutforms, craft2

I am using Craft CMS 2.7.3 and sprout forms 2.6.0 version.

I have created a dropdown field in the craft cms -> fields. How can I fetch this field or render this field in the Sprout form design?

Even if I create a tab and save it. It doesn't get saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off, you will probably want to update to the most recent version of Sprout Forms on Craft 2. As of this message, it looks like v2.6.4 is the most recent version:
https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-forms/releases/tag/v2.6.4

Sprout Forms manages Fields independently of Craft so you will not see any of your Craft Fields when editing a Form. Fields you create for a particular form will only be available to that specific form.

Once you create a Form, you should see a `New Field` button below the initial empty Tab. You will need to add a Field to the Tab before you save in order for the Tab to be saved.

Comment: Thank you updating the Sprout form worked.